# Appropriate action to undertake when the real problem is not related to the question

Tags: discussion, support

As being the most recent occurrence of the (not so accute ;-) ) problem I'm facing is [that precise thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714372/using-the-command-sudo-chrt-r-99-for-a-video-encoding-benchmark-i-always-get/714375?noredirect=1#comment1353646_714375).

After precisely answering OP's question (as worded), read & wrote n+1 comments, I (in the linked case I understand we are two contributors sharing the same understanding) realize that OP's real problem is **in no way** related to the question as worded. (and, BTW, even less with the title).

In the example given, OPs is asking about performance impact of RT scheduling when, in practice, we can discover that OP's real problem is with benchmarking in general.

The question just cannot be edited… (would need to change every word)
It surely should be closed in order for other honest members of the community to avoid wasting their time answering to the question as worded BUT, amongst the reasons offered for closing, I feel just incapable of selecting the most appropriate.

Not to say that, for actually closing, this would need 4 other voters… who would need to carefully read multiple answers & n+1 comments in order to acknowledge the pertinence of the close request…
 I wouldn't myself do that in whatever thread I would not have been myself implied…

< trolling >Hmmm… this being debatable at the price of terdon's 58 gold badges added to Kusalananda's knowledge of bash< /trolling >

So… what is the appropriate action I should undertake ?

Comment: If you feel the question should be closed as unclear, vote to do so and explain your reasoning in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> amongst the reasons offered for closing

You always have the option of adding your own close reason: select “A community-specific reason”, then “Other - add a comment”:

[image: The community-specific “Close” dialog, with the “Other” entry selected]

You then have 458 characters to describe exactly why you think the question should be closed (or slightly more, if you delete the template “I’m voting to close this question because”). Whatever you enter here will be added as a comment on the post, and will be visible to reviewers looking at the question in the review queue.

Comment: Ha! OK then! Thanks! for the info. It won't solve the problem of needing 4 other honest&courageous contributors to get actually closed… even if… I had recently to acknowledge that some contributors get the superpower to close irrespective of the number of voters… ;-P ! No hardfeeling anyhow ! :-)

Comment: Close votes like this usually complete successfully here, and there’s always the possibility that a mod will insta-close. (Hammers for non-mods only apply to duplicates.)